# How to convert a pixel matrix text file to an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have matrix of 32 bit pixels in a text file. I want to convert this data to an actual image.

```
00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

This is my input data store in a .txt file. My expected output is a black image with 2x2 resolution. Is there any specific command in MATLAB to do this?

Comment: have you tried.... reading.... the.... file ?

Comment: I don't think there is a specific command to do this, you will probably have to open the file via `fopen`, read it via `fscanf` or `fgetl` or something like this and then close it via `fclose`. I recommend to read some documentation on the functions I mentioned.

Comment: It looks like a 32 bit greyscale? You might also want to convert your 32bits into its actual Integer representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example code below does the following steps:

1. open the file
2. determine the column count of the matrix
3. read all binary numbers as a cell array of text strings
4. close the file
5. determine the row count of the matrix
6. convert the binary strings to decimal and normalize
7. reshape matrix to the desired column and row count

---

```
function [im, width, height] = load_image(filename)

fid = fopen(filename,'r');

first_line = fgetl(fid);
width = (length(first_line)+1)/33;
frewind(fid);

data = textscan(fid, '%s');

fclose(fid);

height = size(data{1},1) / width;

im = bin2dec(data{:})/2^32;

im = reshape(im, width, height)';
```

---

**example use:**

*data.dat*

```
00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 10000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

```
im = load_image('data.dat');
imshow(im);
```

[image]

Comment: very nice answer! up-ed